# PyQT QTreeWidget iterating

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreewidget

I have two columns in a **QTreeWidget**, one column represents a **list of urls** and the second represents **results**. I have loaded  the list of urls in first column and now I want to iterate this list and during the iteration, change the text in the second column. How to achieve this?

Comment: can you show us the code please?

Comment: If you only have two columns, `QTreeWidget` could be replaced with `QTableWidget`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can call [QTreeWidget.invisibleRootItem()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#invisibleRootItem) to receive the root item, and then use the [QTreeWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html) API to iterate through the items.

Example:

```
root = self.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
child_count = root.childCount()
for i in range(child_count):
    item = root.child(i)
    url = item.text(0) # text at first (0) column
    item.setText(1, 'result from %s' % url) # update result column (1)
```

I am assuming `self.treeWidget` is populated by:

```
self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(2) # two columns, url result
for i in range(10):
    self.treeWidget.insertTopLevelItem(i, QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList('url %s' % i)))
```

Comment: Thanks that is what i wanted to know :)

Comment: This is effectively infeasible to discover merely by reading the official documentation. The traditional means of iterating tree items is via the [`QTreeWidgetItemIterator` helper class](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2014-May/034315.html) – which sadly provides no means of iterating *only* top-level tree items and hence is inapplicable in this common use case. Can we collectively admit that the Qt API is sufficiently obscure as to be useless without StackOverflow? (*Yes. Yes, we can.*)